# str_pad() anonymous function explanation

Tags: php

Please explain to me why I can't put an anonymous function as an argument to str_pad().

Ex:

```
str_pad(function ($num) {
  return ($num > 5) ? "greater" : "less than";
}, 57, '_');
```

Since the function returns a string, how come I can't do this?

Comment: Where does the value of `$num` that is passed come from anyway?

Comment: @AbraCadaver that is irrelevant

Comment: So is the question if you don't have data to pass.  But your question is answered I was just curious as it looked that there was a problem to be solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `str_pad` does not expect a function as its argument, period. It expects a string. You give it a function. It doesn't know what to do with a function. It would need to *execute* the function to receive a string, but that's simply not what it does.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. I was just curious why it didn't work.

Comment: Because that's not what it says [on the tin](http://php.net/str_pad). Always read the instructions on [the tin](http://php.net/manual/en/funcref.php). ;o)

Comment: I always do, I was just curious since a function could in fact return a string. I think PHP should allow function as argument.

Comment: No, it shouldn't in cases like this. There's no need for it. It's pointless to want to write code like this. No language I know of allows arbitrary values to be substituted by a function. In your case, your function even requires an argument to be passed. How can `str_pad` know what argument it's supposed to pass when calling the function?

Answer (score 4):

Because `str_pad` takes a `string` as the first argument, not a function.

Just nest your conditional directly, no need for a function.

```
str_pad(($num > 5) ? "greater" : "less than", 57, '_');
```

Answer (score 3):

Because PHP doesn't work that way. The definition of `str_pad()` is that it wants to receive a string there, not a `callable`. While some functions will let you do that, `str_pad()` is not one of them.